# how to implement this gurobi constraint without error?

Tags: python, gurobi

so I am trying to implement a constraint like this:

[image]

i: frequency index
j: city index
k: city index

The purpose of this constraint is to make sure the same frequency cannot be used in adjacent cities.

The connection/edge between cities 1-6, and other info are defined below:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
m = gp.Model("Problem 2")
freq_cost = 500000
city = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']
edges = [
('c1','c2'), ('c1','c3'), ('c1','c5'),
('c2','c3'), ('c2','c4'), ('c2','c5'), ('c2','c5'),
('c3','c4'), ('c3','c6'),
('c4','c6'),
('c5','c6')]
frequency = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6']
# Profit to broadcast in city I:
profit = {
"c1": 300000,
"c2": 300000,
"c3": 450000,
"c4": 100000,
"c5": 100000,
"c6": 400000,
}
#Create Variables
x = m.addVars(frequency, city , name='x', vtype=GRB.BINARY) #adding X_ij = # of 
freq*# of city
y = m.addVars(frequency , name='y', vtype=GRB.BINARY) #adding y_i
m.update() # Update the model
```

Attempt:

```
for i in frequency: 
    for j in city:
        for k in city:
            if ((j,k) not in edges) and (j != k) and (j > k):
                m.addConstr((x[i,j]+x[i,k] <= 1), "c3")
```

List of constraints generated:

```
c3: 2 x[f1,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f1,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c5] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c5] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c5] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c5] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c5] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c1] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c2] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c5] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: 2 x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c5] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c5] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c5] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c5] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c5] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c5] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c1] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c2] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c3] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c4] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f1,c5] + x[f1,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c1] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c2] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c3] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c4] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f2,c5] + x[f2,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c1] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c2] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c3] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c4] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f3,c5] + x[f3,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c1] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c2] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c3] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c4] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f4,c5] + x[f4,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c1] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c2] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c3] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c4] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f5,c5] + x[f5,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c2] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c3] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c4] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c5] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c1] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c2] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c3] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c4] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
c3: x[f6,c5] + x[f6,c6] <= 1
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Please [don't post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). In addition, posting a fully reproducible example instead would increase your chances of getting helpful answers. For instance, we don't know how your variable `x` is defined. The error message tells you that your loops access variables by indices that haven't been defined.

Comment: Hi Joni, I have edited the post based on your suggestion!  Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: Your second attempt runs without any problems for me. That being said, are you sure you only want to consider the city pairs (j,k) that are not in edges and thus non-adjacent?

Comment: Yeah,the original sentence is "the same frequency cannot be used in adjacent cities".  And for some reason, I am still getting the same error

Comment: And I just restarted my notebook, it is running fine now, and but I don't think it is generating the constraints I am looking for...I feel like my logic has no problem though...

Comment: Like cities that are adjacent are showing up in the constraint (I have updated the constraints generated in the post)  also it is also giving constraints for the same frequency and same city even though I already try to add 2 more conditions to prevent those.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the same frequency cannot be used in adjacent cities, it doesn't make sense to only add the constraint x[i,j] + x[i,k] <= 1 for cities j and k that are non-adjacent ((j,k) is not in edges) for a given frequency i. At the moment, you are imposing that each frequency i cannot be used for *non-adjacent* cities (j,k).